# Add additional sorting to OpenCart product pages

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, opencart

I am desperately trying to sort products in OpenCart category pages by the actual category of the products.

For example, I have these couple categories...

```
Bath
Bath > Faucets
Bath > Toilets
```

I would like to sort the "Bath > Toilets" product to show before the "Bath > Faucets" products when I'm viewing the "Bath" parent category. I have searched the web up and down and cannot find an extension that helps me with this.

I would give individual products sort orders(which I already have) but our store is 50K products and counting so it makes it hard to change sorting over time.

I was thinking that I could add an additional level of sorting to the category pages by sorting by the product category's actual sort order then a secondary sort based on the actual products sort order(which is by default how OC sort products).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: are you want to sort product categories or product ?

Comment: I want to sort product on the category pages based on what category they are in. For example, what can I do if I want to show a certain sub-category above another. I can't unless I resort the products manually in my import spreadsheet.